# A question about "smoothly compatible"

Tags: smooth-manifolds

We say that two charts$(U,\phi), (V,\theta)$ are smoothly compatible if $U \cap V = \emptyset$ or $ \phi \circ \theta^{-1}$ is smooth. Do we also require that $\theta \circ \phi^{-1}$ to be smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the requirement that $\theta\circ\phi^{-1}$ be smooth or not. It makes a difference if you want to ask if two *particular* charts are smoothly compatible. But in the situation you're really interested in (defining a smooth atlas), it doesn't make any difference.

We say that an atlas $\{U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ for a topological manifold $M$ is a ***smooth atlas*** if for each $\alpha,\beta\in A$, the charts $(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)$ and $(U_\beta,\phi_\beta)$ are smoothly compatible. Since this applies equally well to $(U_\beta,\phi_\beta)$ and $(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)$, it follows that each transition map $\phi_\alpha\circ \phi_\beta^{-1}$ is in fact a diffeomorphism, even if you adopted the weaker definition of smooth compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition:** $(U, \phi)$ and $(V,\theta)$ are smoothly compatible if $U \cap V = \emptyset$ or $\phi \circ \theta^{-1}$ is a **$C^{\infty}$-diffeomorphism**.

Therefore, $\theta \circ \phi^{-1}$ is also smooth by the very definition of a $C^{\infty}$-diffeomorphism.